# Problema en especificar el ErrorCorrectionLevel al generar Código QR

Tags: c#, qr

tengo el siguiente código para generar códigos QR (utilizando zxing) en un array de Byte [que paso a report viewer]

```
        BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter() //barcodeWriter para generar un codigo QR (O.O)
        {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, //setearle el tipo de codigo que generara.
            Options = new EncodingOptions()
            {
                Height = 600,
                Width = 600,
                Margin = 0, // el margen que tendra el codigo con el restro de la imagen
            },

        };

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            writer.Write(lDatosFactura[0].QRContenido).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            lDatosFactura[0].QR = ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Todo funciona perfectamente, pero ahora por un proceso normativo, me piden garantizar que el nivel de corrección de error sea 15% (ErrorCorrectionLevel M), le busque por todo lado y no encuentro por donde aumentar ese dato a mi código, alguien por favor que me ayude a adecuar mi código para aumentar lo mencionado.

Me quedo agradecido de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En los `hints` es donde debes agregar esa información  `zXing.Common.EncodingOptions`

```
var cOptions =new EncodingOptions()
        {
            Height = 600,
            Width = 600,
            Margin = 0, // el margen que tendra el codigo con el restro de la imagen
        };
cOptions.Hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
```